# Woocommerce - Conditionally fill some address fields

Tags: php, woocommerce, conditional-statements, checkout, autofill

I wish to fill in some shipping address fields (like street, neighborhood and number) automatically after a selection. For example:

If somebody selects "01 Store - São Paulo", it automatically fills the address of the shop located in São Paulo. (It's only a example).

I've tried thousand of different plugins, filters, hooks and actions... I've looked a thousand of related topics... but with no success.

The payment operators and gateways in Brazil require a fully filled in address form to process payment. But the clients simply hate it!

Any help?

Actually I'm using a trick: I create one product variation for each address, then, I apply a filter or something like this:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'testing_conditional' );

function testing_conditional ( ) {

  global $woocommerce;

    // loop through the cart checking the products
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];

        // checking the product variation ids
    if( $_product->variation_id == 165, 170, 069 ) {

add_filter( 'default_checkout_postcode', 'change_default_checkout_postcode' );

function change_default_checkout_postcode() {
  return '07400470'; // postcode
}

add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_address_1', 'change_default_checkout_shipping_address_1' );

function change_default_checkout_shipping_address_1() {
  return 'Street Name'; 
}

add_filter( 'default_checkout_state', 'change_default_checkout_state' );

function change_default_checkout_state() {
  return 'SP'; // state code
}

add_filter( 'default_checkout_city', 'change_default_checkout_city' );

function change_default_checkout_city() {
  return 'City Name';
}

        }
    }
}
?>
```

But I would like to add a condition to checkout page. Something like this:

```php
<?php

function add_shipping_area_checkout_field( $fields ) {

$fields['shipping']['shipping_area'] = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Shipping Area', 'textdomain' ),
    'placeholder' => _x( 'Shipping Area', 'placeholder', 'textdomain' ),
    'required'    => false,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options'     => array(
        'city 1'  => 'City 1',
        'city 2'  => 'City 2',
        'city 3'  => 'City 3',
        'city 4'  => 'City 4',
    ),
    'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
    'clear'       => true
);
return $fields;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_shipping_area_checkout_field' );

// From here I don't know what to do 

funtion conditional_field_value( $fields ) {

 //if  an user selects City 1

if $fields['shipping']['shipping_area'] = 'city 1' {
  $fields['shipping']['address_1']['value'] = 'Street Name';
  $fields['shipping']['city']['value'] = 'City Name';
  $fields['shipping']['postcode']['value'] = 07400001;
 }
 //if an user selects City 2

if $fields['shipping']['shipping_area'] = 'city 2' {
  $fields['shipping']['address_1']['value'] = 'Street Name 2';
  $fields['shipping']['city']['value'] = 'City Name 2';
  $fields['shipping']['postcode']['value'] = 07400002;
 }

//if an user selects City 3
if $fields['shipping']['shipping_area'] = 'city 3' {
  $fields['shipping']['address_1']['value'] = 'Street Name 3';
  $fields['shipping']['city']['value'] = 'City Name 3';
  $fields['shipping']['postcode']['value'] = 07000003;
 }
}

?>
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: Can you include your code thus far?